# Polymorphic association foreign_type sets ancestor type instead current, using STI class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphic-associations, single-table-inheritance

I have

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base; end

class Porsche < Car
  has_many :page_items, :as=>:itemable, :dependent=>:destroy
end
```

I have to mention that I'm using a single table called `cars` which has a field `type`.

```
class PageItem<ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :itemable, :polymorphic=>true
end
```

When I do

```
  a = PageItem.new
  a.itemable = Porsche.new
  a.itemable
  #<Porsche id: nil, type: "Porsche", name: nil, ..etc>

  a.itemable_type
  => "Car"
```

And it should be

```
  a.itemable_type
  => "Porsche"
```

Do anybody have an idea about this?

**Update**

According to `bor1s`'s answer probably this is the right behaviour. So if is it, then my question is how can I set it to `Porsche` implicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Porshe is *virtual* model, it is not really exist in in database, it just has `type` field to know that it is Porshe. Maybe you should get rid of STI and use say `type` column to save Car model with type of Porshe and use `scope` to find *porshes*. I hope I helped you alittle.

Comment: Well this is the purpose of STI inheritance I guess, to use the same table for different classes to store.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add `type` field to the `Car` table, you'll be able to get `Porsche` type using : 
  `PageItem.new(:itemable => Porsche.new).itemable.type`